# WSO2 - Where in the source is the link between SCIM interface and IS identity management?

Tags: wso2, scim

I found Charon (SCIM) in the WSO2 source code and have that working. But that source tree only has a sample server implementation. Where in the WSO2 source tree do I find the implementation that exposes WSO2's underlying identity management?

Answer (score 1):

WSO2 charon is the SCIM protocol implementation, which can be used in any application to support SCIM based provisioning support. In WSO2 identity server it expose its SCIM endpoints through SCIM provider component. And underline it will call the user core identity management capabilities. Additional details about this implementation can be found [here](http://hasini-gunasinghe.blogspot.com/2012/11/wso2-identity-server-as-scim-service.html).